# i want to move the images to another directory if the status of the image is 1(active) i am able to move one record but not all

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

I want a simple guide on how can i transfer the images with active status to another directory here is my code:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
$path = public_path('images\products');
$allfiles = scandir($path);
$allfiles = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));
$files = array();

foreach ($allfiles as $filename) {
    $file= File::get(public_path('images/products/'.$filename));
    $files[] = [
        "file_name"=>$filename];
    }
        // return $filename;

            foreach($files as $file){
                $exists[] = DB::table('tw_products')
                    // ->where('image', '=', $file['file_name'])
                    ->where('status', '=', 1)
                    ->get('image', '=', $file['file_name']);
                    // return $exists;
                    if($exists[] = 'images/products/'.$file['file_name']){
                    File::copy('images/products/'.$file['file_name'],'images/ActiveProducts/'.$file['file_name']);
                    echo "File Moved from (images/products/".$file['file_name'] . ")<br />";
                }

            }

  });
```

now all the files are being copied but m not sure why it's not filtering the images
I want to compare the DB items(image and status) if the status of the image = 1 that image will be moved to another directory...

Comment: Not sure but there's a bug if($users = $file['file_name']){ , I suspect you're trying to do a comparison here not an assignment.

Comment: I made some changes but all the images are being copied I am not sure why

Answer (score 0):

Try with count instead of get which will return 0 or 1 depending on the file beeing active or not

```
foreach($files as $file){
    $exists = DB::table('tw_products')
        ->where('image', '=', $file['file_name'])
        ->where('status', '=', 1)
        ->count();
    if($exists){
        File::copy('images/products/'.$file['file_name'],'images/ActiveProducts/'.$file['file_name']);
        echo "File Moved";
    }
}
```

I suggest you do it as a command or in tinker to avoid timing out

Comment: count is not really working its displaying nothing